# Subscibe not print out any log if using publishOn in Project Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've got a very simple stream based on the book of *`Hands-On Reactive Programming in Spring 5`*.

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
    .concatMap(i -> Flux.range(0, i).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
    .subscribe(log::info);
```

However, there's no console output at all. But if I add `doOnNext` after `just`:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3).doOnNext(log::debug).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
    .concatMap(i -> Flux.range(0, i).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
    .subscribe(log::info);
```

then I can get both output of debug and info. May I know why?

Edit 1:
There's the console output of the following stream:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3).doOnNext(log::debug)
    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())).doOnNext(log::warn)
    .concatMap(i -> Flux.range(0, i).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()))
    .subscribe(log::info);
```

And output:

```
[main] INFO ReactiveTest - 1
[main] INFO ReactiveTest - 2
[elastic-2] WARN ReactiveTest - 1
[main] INFO ReactiveTest - 3
[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 0
[elastic-2] WARN ReactiveTest - 2

[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 0
[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 1
[elastic-2] WARN ReactiveTest - 3
[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 0
[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 1
[elastic-2] DEBUG ReactiveTest - 2
```

I think the log messages prove that the function in `subscribe` will be called at the same thread as the function of `concatMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first program is probably terminating right after you call `subscribe`. From the docs of `subscribe`:

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will immediately
>   return control to the calling thread. This can give the impression the consumer is
>   not invoked when executing in a main thread or a unit test for instance.

In second program, `doOnNext` is invoked in the middle of processing, so it has time to output all the results. If you run the program many times you will see that it sometimes is not able to output the second log.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually, if I add `Thread.sleep`, the log messages will show then.

Comment: This is actually a very bad design decision to use `Thread.sleep` inside a reactor thread just to show a log message...